# Carousel Transitions not Responding

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am pretty new to react and bootstrap. I picked some bootstrap carousel source code, tried to implement it in my reactjs app. The problem is the next and previous buttons are not responding.
Also, th images are not automatically changing.

```
import React from 'react';
import img1 from '../images/img1.jpg';
import img2 from '../images/img2.jpg';
import img3 from '../images/img3.jpg';
import img4 from '../images/img4.jpg';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';

const ImageShow = ({imagesData}) => {

const { caption1,caption2, caption3, caption4 } = imagesData;

console.log(img1);
    return(
    <div id="myCarousel" className="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        {/* indicators */}
        <ol className="carousel-indicators" role="listbox">
            <li data-target='#myCarousel' data-slide-to="0" className="active"></li>
            <li data-target='#myCarousel' data-slide-to="1" ></li>
            <li data-target='#myCarousel' data-slide-to="2" ></li>
            <li data-target='#myCarousel' data-slide-to="3" ></li>
        </ol>

        {/* wrapper for slides */}
        <div className="carousel-inner">
            <div className="imageWidth item active">
                <img src={img1} alt={caption1} />
            </div>

            <div className="imageWidth item">
                <img src={img2} alt={caption2} />
            </div>

            <div className="imageWidth item">
                <img src={img3} alt={caption3} />
            </div>

            <div className="imageWidth item">
                <img src={img4} alt={caption4} />
            </div>
        </div>

        {/* left and right controls */}
        <a className="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
            <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
            <span className="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>

        <a className="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
            <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
            <span className="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>);
}

export default ImageShow;
```

How do I get the click events to work in my react app?

Comment: Note: `<img>` does not use or need a closing slash and never has.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the React component has rendered. Lookup the documentation of how to use the carousel https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#carousel

It gives example of manually setting up carousel `$('#myCarousel').carousel()`

Change your React component to extend from `React.Component`

Add that manual setup into your `componentDidMount` method

```jsx
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
componentDidMount(){
 window.$(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this)).carousel();
}
```